# Dql select in doctrine vs sql query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

What is the benefit of use DQL in 'select' statement in doctrine vs native sql?

e.g

```
     $qb = $em->getRepository('repositoryname')->createQueryBuilder('r);
     $qb->someDqlCondition();
     $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

vs

```
     $sql = 'string with SELECT sql statement'
     $query = $em->->createQuery($sql)
     $query->getResult();
```

I discuss about it with my colleague and he say that native sql is better.
I think that dql give us ability to change database driver.Is there any other benefit of using dql?    What about performance?

Comment: DQL is more portable between database instead of native sql

Comment: Also, performance are not an issue if you use the query cache, that saves the translation between SQL and DQL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Doctrine Query Language](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)** (DQL) is like an abstraction of your queries. This makes queries independent of the version or type of (SQL) database that your project is built on.

From the documentation:

> You need to think about DQL as a query language for your object model, not for your relational schema.

It also means (like @Matteo says in his comment) that you can more easily port your project on another type without having to rewrite all your queries.

Using **[the doctrine `QueryBuilder`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)** takes this abstraction to the next level.